# Local singularity image in snakemake workflow on AWS eks with --kubernetes option

Tags: kubernetes, snakemake, amazon-eks, singularity-container

I am trying to use Snakemake on AWS EKS, running shell commands in singularity containers. If I understood correctly, Snakemake is then run as a container itself by kubernetes, so I would run a singularity container inside a Pod.
I have a ubuntu image in the same folder of the Snakefile.
How do I tell Singularity the path where the image is stored?

I have tried to run the workflow specifying an image in the DockerHub and it works perfectly.
However I cannot make it work with images stored in my EC2 instance, if I specify --kubernetes flag (if I run it without --kubernetes, it runs perfectly also with local images). I tried specifying the path of the image on the EC2 instance, but it is not working.

My Snakefile looks something like that:

```
rule test:
    singularity:
        "ubuntu.simg"
    output:
        "out.txt"
    shell:
        "cat /etc/os-release > {output}"
```

and I run Snakemake with the command:

```
snakemake --kubernetes --default-remote-provider S3 --default-remote-prefix S3-bucket-name --use-singularity
```

Desired output is the file "out.txt" created in the specified s3 bucket with the info about the os release of the "ubuntu.sigm" container.
The actual result is a failed job. If I inspect with

```
kubectl logs snakejob-c25eaf1f-6ad4-505e-94a0-646543a59d33
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR  : Image path ubuntu.simg doesn't exist: No such file or directory
ABORT  : Retval = 255
```

Anyone who had the same issue?

Comment: It looks like the environment inside the kubernetes is not what you're expecting to be there, or at least in a different directory than you're expecting. What happens if you remove the `singularity` part of the rule, and change the shell content to `echo $PWD; ls -la`?

Comment: I get
`/workdir
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  94 Jul  2 12:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  46 Jul  2 12:39 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  23 Jul  2 12:39 ..2019_07_02_12_39_31.635282758
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  31 Jul  2 12:39 ..data -> ..2019_07_02_12_39_31.635282758
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 113 Jul  2 12:39 .snakemake
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  16 Jul  2 12:39 Snakefile -> ..data/Snakefile
[Tue Jul  2 12:39:32 2019]
Finished job 0.
1 of 1 steps (100%) done
Complete log: /workdir/.snakemake/log/2019-07-02T123932.011750.snakemake.log`

Comment: Formatting gets a little wonky in these comments, but you may also want to look into the `..data` and `.snakemake` directories. If the image is still not there, it looks like the bucket content is not getting loaded into the pod. That could be from the pods not having the correct permissions or needing additional params.

Comment: The image is not in ..data nor in .snakemake, nor in any other subfolder. When the image gets pulled automatically from DockerHub (named docker://image_name) I see a new image inside the pod in .snakemake/singularity. If however I try to specify that image in the input singularity field with `singularity: "/workdir/.snakemake/image_name.simg" ` I get the same error as above.